# RegExp expression to target all files in a folder and its subfolders for workbox.routing / service worker

Tags: regex, service-worker, workbox

Hej!

I'm pretty new to service worker in general, so I hope the question is not (too) dumb. ^^

I use the workbox plugin (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) to handle the service worker. Now I need a RegExp to target all files within a folder and all files within all subfolders in this folder to add them to the list of the service worker cache. I use

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute
```

to target the files I want to cache with the service worker. 
Is this possible at all?

Thanks for your help, 
All the best

Lucas

Answer (score 0):

You can register a route that matches a given URL path prefix shared by all of the files and sub-directories:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  // This will match requests for
  // /path/, /path/index.html, /path/subdir/a.jpg, etc.
  new RegExp('^/path/'),
  // Use whatever strategy you want.
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({...})
);
```

Comment: Hi Jeff Posnick. Could you please let me know how can I integrate pwa with reactjs?